# Keynote: Scoreboard

Tags: keynote, imovie

Because of the limited features in imovie i found a solution to add a scoreboard (numbers showing current score of a match) to a movie by using a keynote presentation and export this one as quicktime movie. So i created a keynote presentation with green background and a scoreboard layer. Now it would be lot of work to create a new slide, everytime the score (of a billard match) changes. So i want to automate it. If i press key '1' than player one should get one point. And if i press '2' then player to should get the point.

In powerpoint i would do this via macros. Unfortunatly in keynote there are no macros. And with animations it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea how i could automate my scoreboard keynote?

Answer (score 1):

Your thread gave me an idea.  I created a scoreboard in keynote and then used screencast (search it) to record the slideshow, and then edited it in imovie.  Comment back if you'd like to see